# Creating a multilayer drop down nav bar

Tags: html-lists

I find it challenging in creating a responsive nav bars that contains multilayer pages, it contains the contact page which also has nav bars embedded in it likewise the connect page and the product page

I tried using HTML and css with JavaScript,I have a very hard time in getting this nav bars to work